# Android GCM not letting me sleep

Tags: java, android

I've made two apps to work with GCM notification in one I've done that using my own php server to store reg ids and then send notification to app users using GCM . and i've coded it myself in java also to receive that notification successfully i've done that using documentation of Google Cloud Messaging

So in 1st app which i coded manually i'm getting all notifications as i was expecting then there was problem that screen was not getting on while i receiver notifications . I've accomplished that also using WAKE_LOCK.

Even my app not present in ram of device which we mostly now a days we use hold on menu button and clear ram.

but still i get notifications.

Ok so here 1st app story ends.

Now let's go towards second app 
I've made that using https://onesignal.com SDK 
That was so amazing and easy and i've done it earlier. 
just this line of code did all.

```
OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
```

So every thing is working and all is done . But problem is that when this app is cleared from ram like i defined above i don't get even single notification then to be sure more i check my cell phone running app section and i was not able to find my 1st and 2nd app there but i found google play services running 5 services when i tapped on that i got that gcm is also running . So i'm not getting that what can be the issue with 2nd app ? what i should do to make it like 1st one with this sdk

I'm really very worried and any help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm in your 2nd app with OneSignal you are sending a new notification from OneSignal each time? If you're replaying a GCM payload the OneSignal SDK will omit processing it to prevent duplicates.

Which device and Android version are you seeing this issue on? Test on multiple OS versions if possible.

Also check the logcat when you kill your app and when you send a notification from OneSignal. It sounds like your app could be getting put into a "Force Stopped" state. See the following gist for an example of the logcat messages that show from this.
https://gist.github.com/jkasten2/fb83b1df754cf26df378

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried it on HUAWEI p8 lite and then SAMSUNG 4.3 OS ANDROID

Comment: After that i tried it on huawei honor 4 and all devices are behaving same on this app and

Comment: @HumzaMalik Can you send another one with any filtering? There are system and GCM logs that are missing. Also if you have proguard / minifyenabled turned on can you test with it off.

Comment: i've checked not any proguard etc enabled and when ever i start app and then clear it from ram and then send notification from your server i just receiver this log data

Comment: The following errors look to be the root of the cause. Are you building with Android Studio or Eclipse?

`04-15 23:50:24.480 31891-31891/com.mazahub.ncbae I/art: Can not find class: Lcom/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmReceiver;
04-15 23:50:24.490 31891-31891/com.mazahub.ncbae I/art: Can not find class: Lcom/onesignal/GcmIntentService;
04-15 23:50:24.490 31891-31891/com.mazahub.ncbae I/art: Can not find class: Lcom/onesignal/GcmBroadcastReceiver;`

Comment: I'm using Android Studio

Comment: While app in background i'm able to receive notification

Comment: Now last one when i don't get notificaiton even gcm service is running under google play services. 

When i swipe recent apps like every one do in android
http://pasted.co/63e6dade

Comment: It seems when your APK is built it is not putting in the required classes noted above. Just to confirm `com.mazahub.ncbae` is your Android Package name?

Can you try the OneSignal example project to see if there is just an issue with your project setup.
https://github.com/one-signal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/tree/master/Examples/AndroidStudio

Comment: Ok let me try :) and yes i'm sure about my package etc and i'm getting notification in just one state which i mentioned above that when app is in background state ..... If not providing class then i would not have got notification. So i think so any other issue btw let me try demo app of one signal :)

Comment: Getting these errors while running your example app :

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the errors or the notification issue you're seeing on Android 6.0.1, 5.0.2, 4.4.2, or 4.2.2. In your last logcat I see your app is in a "force stopped" state from the following GCM error. `04-15 23:57:37.640 4362-4362/? W/GCM-DMM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.mazahub.ncbae (has extras) }`

Comment: But i'm not forcestopping app then what can be the problem

Comment: The `result=CANCELLED` GCM entry I found in your last log confirms that Google Play services received the GCM payload but could not start your app due to it being in the "Forced Stopped" state. In your case it is most likely getting into this state from a crash or the manufactures of your test devices customized Android to put apps into this state in other cases.